# how to display images from nestjs server to Angular

Tags: html, angular, file, nestjs

When I upload a product from Angular side, It Post the product with imagepath, and the image is getting stored in the NestJs folder also, but I can not display product with it's image. The product is displaying at frontend but without it's image that is referenced and saved at the backend.

**Anguar FrontEnd Code .ts**

```
 export class BooksComponent implements OnInit {
      BookForm = new FormGroup({
        _id: new FormControl(''),
        name: new FormControl(''),
        author: new FormControl(''),
        price: new FormControl(''),
        genres_name: new FormControl(''),
        coverimage: new FormControl(''),
      });
      results?: Book[] = [];
      searchedText: string = '';
      constructor(
        private readonly apiService: ApiService,
        private router: Router
      ) {}
    
      ngOnInit() {
        this.apiService.getallbooks().subscribe((data) => {
          this.results = data;
    
          console.log(this.results);
        });
      }
```

**Frontend html code.I'm getting all the information but not the image, here I'm providing `src in img tag to display images`**

```
<div class="grid" *ngFor="let result of results">
    <div class="blog-card spring-fever" style="padding: 0.5rem; z-index: 100">
      <img
        class="image"
        src="http://localhost:3000/{{ result.coverimage }}"
        alt=""
        height="400px"
        width="250px"
        style="border: 1px solid red"
      />
```

**This is the information of the Product that is coming from the backend**
[image]

**And when I try like this `src="{{result.coverimage}}"` or `[src]="result.coverimage"` I got error `localhost:4200/assets/imagename` not found(404). well that is obvoius!.  because there is not such path, 4200 is for Angular. but I'm uploading the images at the backend assets folder which is located at `localhost:3000/assets/`, and we always upload files to backend for dynamic approach from database**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your highlighted part of your post you ask how to display the image, i.e you suspect the problem is in the frontend. However there is a missing part from the provided context. In the line where the `html` magic happens (The `img` tag `src` attribute).

There you are string interpolating a property called `coverimage` under the `results` object. We do not see what is inside the `coverimage` from your backend response in the frontend screenshot. If it is an `id` of a document then it will not be parsed correctly. The `src` attribute accepts:
`APNG`, `AVIF`, `GIF`, `JPEG`, `PNG`, `SVG`, and `WebP`. Or `base64` (which seems not the case here).

When you have the image with one of the [acceptable supported formats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#supported_image_formats) as stated in MDN correct you can map the property to the `src` attribute either via

1- string interpolation:

```
<img src="{{imagePath}}" />
```

2- property binding:

```
<img [src]="imagePath" />
```

The second way is more popular, but both work fine.

PS: it is a best practice and accessibility recommended to populate the `alt=""` property

Comment: the `coverimage` property is a string type proprety of the book class. And in the backend the `coverimage` property holds the path of the image that is uploaded. So according to my understanding the `coverimage under the result object` at frontend , should access the image because the path for the image is stored, or something like that. Also is there some way to know what I'm getting inside `coverimage` property from backend? , as you are telling me that we don't know what is coming from backend.

Comment: I have updated my question with some new information and screenshots please observe them.

Comment: okay the path mapping is correct in the Frontend but the correct format of the URL points to something that does not exist. As you already mentioned yourself the assets/image is served under a different PORT which is the server address. Make sure your backend server localhost:3000 is up and running and you can access your image when both server and client are up

Answer (score 0):

**If you are struggling to display the images coming from server, like I was, or you are struggling with the data that is coming NestJs. Then this might work for you as it worked for me.**

**So in my case** I had a  list of books and each book has path for its image. I was using `ngFor` and set the image `src` with the path. That is the right way. But the images were not visible and Network was showing images as `text/html` type. The actual issue here was not the `type`,the actual issue was in my `URL`.I had a folder in NestJs server by the name of `assets`,that is preset at `root`, and I had set the path for the images(in NestJs file upload code), like this `./assets/`. That is also the correct way to set the destination folder.I was able to see the images at browser like this `http://localhost:3000/imagename.png`,and that means my server configured to server/serve my images over root URL that's why I  can access them `http://localhost:3000/imagename.png`. But my `api` was returning images in a format that contains `./assets/` in the URL.

**So with the following code**

```
<div *ngIf="result.coverimage">
          <img
            class="image"
            src="http://localhost:3000/{{ result.coverimage }}"
            alt=""
            height="400px"
            width="250px"
            style="border: 1px solid red"
          />
        </div>
```

I am assuming that I'm hitting the Url like this  `http:localhost:3000/imagename.png`. But actually Angular was seeing the URL like this `http:localhost:3000/./assets/imagename.png`. And **this is note the correct URL Format**. Urls don't work with `.` or `,`.Also becasue my server is configured at root, this url`http;//localhost:3000/assets/imagename.png` is also wrong.And `root` means that, whatever the thing is set at `root`, that is directly access able after your server's port number. Example `http://localhost:YourServerPortNumber/TheThing_Set_at_Root`.

> **So the solution for this issue is the following**

```
src="http://localhost:3000/{{
              result.coverimage.replace('./assets/', '')
            }}"
```

With above `.replace('./assets/', '')` we are removing the `./assets/` and repalcing it with `''` empty space. So now URL is in this format`http://localhost:3000/imagename.png`.